# Return to edit view after validation failed htm attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a simple view that is used to edit some basic information. Their is an "NA" checkbox if the data is not required.

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonInfo[i].Reference, "Enter a reference", new { disabled = Model.PersonInfo[i].NotApplicable }) 

   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PersonInfo[i].NotApplicable, new
       {
           onclick = "ChangeEnabledState(" + i + ");"

       })
```

When the user clicks the NA checkbox, it calles a javascript function that disables all the controls for that person.

I have a problem with the following scenario:

1. User creates a new "Person info" and sets it to NA (so all fields get disabled)
2. User then goes back into the edit view, unchecks the checkbox (enables the views)
3. User enters some invalid data in one of the texboxes
4. User clicks save, validation fails and the errors are added to the model
5. As the textboxes being disabled is set based on the model, they are disabled but the checkbox inst checked. So the user has to click the checkbox twice to re enable them.

Is there a clean way of updateing the viewmodel so the fields are not disabled in the above scenario. I already tried a jquery document.ready to check the checbox and enable/disable but feel there must be a much more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ajax forms you have a paramater called AjaxOptions. For AjaxOptions you can define a OnBegin, OnSucces, OnComplete, OnSucces, OnFailure.

here you can pass in a javascript function which is called when the request starts or when it is finished or when validation failed like in your question.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MethodName", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions { OnFailure="EnableForm()" })
```

Comment: I ma not using AjaxForms unfotunately, just the standard html

Comment: You can simple change Html.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm to start using ajax forms for this view

Comment: I have not really used the Ajax forms before, does the OnError get called if server side validation fails?

Comment: I don't know about the OnError attribute? Personally i would go with the OnComplete. A full reference can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.aspx

Comment: I have added the following..                                                     @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "OnComplete" })) and it is not calling the oncomplee method when validation fails, do i need to import anything?

Comment: No you don't need tot include something. But you forgot the function () you'll have to use OnComplete = "OnComplete()" And make sure you provide all the requered parameteres for the ajaxform. not only the ajaxoptions

Comment: I have changed it to ...........................@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "alert('oncomplete fired')", OnSuccess = "alert('oncsuccess fired')", OnFailure = "alert('onfailure fired')" }))              The validation fails and highlights the invalid fields, but none of the alert boxes appear